# Adding headers to an Akka HTTP HttpRequest

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have an existing Akka HTTP [`HttpRequest`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.7/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpRequest.html) and I want to add two headers to it.

```
val req: HttpRequest = ???
val hs: Seq[HttpHeader] = Seq(RawHeader("a", "b"))
req.addHeaders(hs)
```

Expected:

- a new `HttpRequest` object with the additional headers

Actual:

- `.addHeaders` expects a `java.lang.Iterable` and does not compile.

What is the recommended way of doing this in Scala?

There is a workaround, but it's a bit cludgy:

```
req.withHeaders(req.headers ++ hs)
```

Running Scala 2.12.8 and Akka HTTP 10.1.7.

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround that is maybe a tiny sliver less cludgy. This is approximately how `addHeaders` is [defined in the source](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/a82046ee6d1682fcd5b93ace085155c80e7713ca/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpMessage.scala#L193). I unfortunately have no clue why `addHeaders` is not exposed in the scala api.

```
req.mapHeaders(_ ++ hs)
```

Comment: Neat and thanks for the link to the sources - I check them too rarely. The real answer seems to be to implement .addHeaders on the Scala API but I don't really work with Akka HTTP at the moment, so won't be the one doing it.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to use `foldLeft` and [`addHeader`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.7/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpRequest.html#addHeader(header:akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpHeader):HttpMessage.this.Self):

```
val req: HttpRequest = ???
val hs: Seq[HttpHeader] = Seq(RawHeader("a", "b"))

hs.foldLeft(req)((r, h) => r.addHeader(h))
```

Comment: It's still not very readable. I wonder if there's a reason why '.addheaders' is for Java API but not Scala.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the existing HttpRequest to a new HttpRequest with headers

```
val req: HttpRequest = ???
val hs: Seq[HttpHeader] = Seq(RawHeader("a", "b"))
val reqWithHeaders: HttpRequest = req.copy(headers=hs)
```

Comment: Does this append to or replace the earlier headers?

Comment: This replaces earlier headers. If you want earlier headers too change it to 
`val reqWithHeaders: HttpRequest = req.copy(headers = this.headers ++ hs)`

Comment: ..which is not very different from the workaround in my question.
Anyhow, none of the answers have mentioned why Akka HTTP would support one syntax (`.addHeaders`) only for the Java API. That was intended to be the question.

Comment: I am not sure but I think
Scala HttpHeader extends jm.HttpHeader(akka.http.javadsl.model, Java Model)
And `addHeaders, withHeaders` are methods of jm.HttpHeaders,
So to override them method signature must be same as Jm.HttpHeaders method.
Hence  Scala `HttpHeaders` take java Iterable for some of its method.

Again the answer is my understanding from the source code. Feel free to correct me.